# Marketing Cloud Pause Sync Contact Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder, data-model, data-designer

I have synchronized the objects "Account" and "Contact" in my Marketing Cloud org.  In case I wanted to pause the synchronization for the "Contact" Object, will it affect the rest of the objects that depend on it? Meaning that in the Data Designer "Contact" comes first and "Account" is linked to Contact.

I use the object "Account "to send emails, so, the Account ID is related to SubscriberKey in Email Studio.

What happens if I pause Sync for Contact Object and delete all contacts associated with the Contact Object in MC? Will my data model be affected?

Comment: This is a bad pattern. The sendable object is the Contact, not the Account and I'd recommend not trying to fight it. There's a variety of design decisions that have gone into the way subscribers/contacts in Marketing Cloud relate the CRM contacts/leads that you're attempting to short circuit, like management of unsubscriptions and the way the data model's defined in Contact Builder. If you're doing this to sidestep billing for contacts in SFMC, look at filtering the contacts you bring in using Data Stream, but don't bother with sending to accounts. It's a bad idea.

Comment: @Macca thank you so very much for your response. The issue we are facing and reason why we use Account ID as SubscribeyKey is because the model in Salesforce CRM is based in Person Account. The implementation is a multicloud one: Salesforce Service, SF Ecommerce and Marketing Cloud. The Service connector with Ecommerce requires Person Account to be enabled, as the clients are final ones. The main issues we are facing is as you previously mentioned, Contacts being billed.

Comment: @Macca Thats why we would like to stop some how the sync in Marketing cloud with Contacts and then eliminate them, without the rest of the objects being sync affected.

Comment: You should anyway use PersonContactId as the Subscriberkey, not AccountId. You can read that ID from the Account object, as you rightly suppose, but Account ID is NOT a good subscriberkey. JourneyBuilder "salesforce data events" only accept User, Lead, Contact as "person" objects that can be injected "as a person into the journey" - definitely reconsider on that part.

Comment: @JonasLamberty thanks for your response! The issue I am now facing is that sync has already been done and Subscriber Key has been linked to PersonAccount ID. In Order to switch to PersonContactID. I would need to: pause Sync, eliminate all contacts that entered through sync, Sync relating Subscriber Key to PersonContact ID. Is this right? Isnt there an easier way to do it?

Comment: It would involve stop of synch, a contact deletion with all effects (loss of history, subscription status,...)  and resynch, so do not go into this haphazardly. It should be worth it though, you don't want to have an implementation ignore the systemic facts. The other option is "subscriber key migration" which is costly, involves SF and a sending stop. general consensus here is to try and avoid that.